# How do I convert a pandas column of datetime64 objects to the year?

Tags: pandas, datetime64

I'm working with a pandas dataframe in which one column is a datetime64 object. I need to plot a bar chart of the number of rows per year, and also slice the dataframe for a month range (e.g. January 2011 to March 2011). I suppose I could add a column that captures only the year or month, but how can I do so?

I ran

```
df['year'], df['month'] = df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.month
df
```

but got an AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Nope, not working. Gets a really long exception, I'll post it in the question.

Comment: Hmm ok. I reran some more code from my notebook and it seems to be working well - so I would guess that it's because when I got the exception, I hadn't re-ran the conversion of to_datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked was, as answered in other questions:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'], df['month'] = df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.month
```

What made my situation different was that I did my work **on a Jupyter notebook** last night and went to sleep. So when I booted my computer again, the lines of code that included the conversion of my datetime column to a `datetime64` object *had not been run*. Silly me. After I reran them, the code worked.

Comment: hello ryan! please mark the question as closed by checking the green tick.